# calling a method with parameters using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python snippet which uses the REST API to pull the data. The function take 3 parameters namely URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD. Now i want a Gui for the same scenario.I'm using tkinter but cannot figure out how a button calls methods with parameters.
this is the sample python code:

```
def example(url, user, password):
     with OciRest(url, user, password) as oci:
        storages = oci.get('assets/storages')

        for storage in storages:
            print('Storage %s : %s' % (storage['family'], storage['name']))

            storage_pools = oci.get(storage['self'] + '/storagePools')
            for storage_pool in storage_pools:
                print('   SP %s: %.3fTB' %(storage_pool['name'],
                   storage_pool['capacity']['total']['value'] / 1024.0 / 1024.0))



if __name__ == '__main__':
     options = parse_command_line()
     example(options.url, options.user, options.password)
```

Now i want the GUI which has url,username,password and when i click on submit button the code should invoke.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: If the answer by Bryan solved your problem, you should accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to have your button call a function which gets the values and calls your function. Doing that, you don't have to pass parameters in your button command.

```
def on_button():
    url = urlEntry.get()
    username = usernameEntry.get()
    password = passwordEntry.get()

    example(url, username, password)

...
button = tk.Button(..., command=on_button)
```